# postLink not deleting record in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to delete record using postLink but in one place it is working and in the other view it gives following error:

> Unexpected field 'example1_length' in POST data
>   It does not enter in the category controller.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('<button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"></button>',
                array('action'=> 'delete', $cat->category_id),array('class'=> 'tip','escape'   => false,'confirm'  => 'Are you sure ?')); ?>
```

> CategoriesController.php

```
 public function delete($id)
        {
            if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
            {
            $categories = $this->Categories->get($id);
            if ($this->Categories->delete($categories)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The Category with id: {0} has been deleted.', h($id)));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view']);
            }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->autoRender = false;
                echo "you are not authorized to view this page";
            }
        }
```

When error page is displayed it shows products controller url but i'm working on category controller. Please help to sort out this issue.

Comment: You're not using `controller` key in array on the second argument of `postLink` method. Maybe You are on action view from Prouducts controller? If yes, use additionally `controller` key

Comment: Kicaj: changed controller but the same results.   echo $this->Form->postLink('<button class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"></button>',
                array('controller'=>'categories','action'=> 'delete_cat', $cat->category_id),array('class'=> 'tip','escape'   => false,'confirm'  => 'Are you sure ?')); ?>

Comment: Controller names should be capitalized: `'controller' => 'Categories'`.